# Single word for something that is 'sound producing'

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word for "sound producing".

What do you call something that produces sound?

Example: Radio is ___________ (sound producing) but I need a single word.

Comment: Audible? Or its synonyms.

Comment: Why not simply “audio”? Radio is (or *has*) audio.

Comment: Elements of some kind vibrating in air produce what we call sound, so how about *vibrelement*? Radios and other sources of sound contain *vibrelements*. It's one "word". :-)

Comment: "sound producible" means that it can be produced by sound, not that it produces sound. You want to say "sound producing" instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Soniferous* is what you're looking for.

> **Soniferous:** Producing or conducting sound.
>
> Example: Soniferous marine animals — **[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soniferous)**

---

**How I found it:**

I combined *soni* and *ferous* to make an adjective:

*Soni* of *sonication* + *(-iferous)* → ***Soniferous***.

*Sonication* is a noun which means *relating to sound*. It's derived from *sonic*.

**Sonic** is an adjective which means:

> Denoting, relating to, or of the nature of sound or sound waves.
>
> Example: The whales emit sonic pulse systems — **[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sonic)**

**-Ferous** is a suffix which is defined by **[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-ferous)** as:

> **-ferous** (also -iferous): Having, bearing, or containing (a specified thing)
>
> Examples: Carboniferous, pestiferous.
>
> **Origin:**
> From French -fère or Latin -fer *‘producing’*, from ferre ‘to bear’.

First I combined *sono* of *sonography* and some adjective forming suffixes like *ful*, *ive*, *ic* etc and googled them but did not find any useful results. But googled *sonoferous*, the second result was 'soniferous' so I then googled soniferous and found its definition.

Quote from [**IBT UK**](https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/ocean-acidification-could-make-sea-much-quieter-snapping-shrimp-stop-ticking-1549850):

> The most common sources of marine biological sounds are snapping shrimp snaps, sea urchin raspings and fish vocalisations. Snapping shrimp (family Alpheidae), are the most ubiquitous and noisy *soniferous* animals in coastal ecosystems.

Comment: @Decapitated Nice etymological sleuthing!

Answer (score 4):

If you think of television as a *visual* medium, then the obvious equivalent word would be *aural*.  The word is often used in educational contexts but may be less familiar more widely.  You could otherwise speak of a *sound* medium.  You would, I think, be forgiven by the possible ambiguity.   *Aural* is better.

Answer (score 4):

Your other apparent option would be ***sonic***
From M-W:   capable of uttering sounds; utilizing, produced by, or relating to sound waves

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

- Radio is/has **sound**

If you're talking about something that's more than sound, you need to use the verb *has*:

- TV has sound

Why would I suggest this? Because it's extremely natural and it works in virtually any context. (You might say it's so natural that it seems silly to even suggest this as an answer!) It's neutral in connotation and formality. I offer no definitions because it can be used to communicate with anyone of any level of English fluency.

Here are some examples in use:

- > Live radio is sound transmitted by radio waves, as the sound happens. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_radio))
- > Even though radio is sound only, nonverbal communication is still important. ([Speaking via Electronic Media](https://open.lib.umn.edu/communication/chapter/12-4-speaking-via-electronic-media/))
- > Radio has sound, but no text or visuals. Television has sound, video and, theoretically, it can also display text. ([Teens and the Media](https://books.google.com/books?id=pFuXDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&lpg=PT95&dq=%22radio+has+sound%22))

You can also sometimes use "**audio**" instead of "sound", with the difference being that "audio" is usually used only for sound that came from somewhere else (e.g. it's a recording or a speaker that you're hearing). For example:

- > Radio is audio and audio is sound. Voice is sound and sound is audio. ([How Technology Helps Radio and Its Listeners](https://www.radioworld.com/columns-and-views/rab-audio-technology-helps-radio))

(Also that last source shows us another example of flexibility here with the expressions "audio medium", "audio technology", etc.: noun adjuncts!)

Answer (score 0):

Not very descriptive so, here's what ***a*** radio is, ***what*** radio is, and what radio ***does***.

A [transistor radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_radio) *is* **an** [**electroacoustic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustical_engineering#Electroacoustics) device used to reproduce sound via an integral speaker(s) or an ear piece(s).

"[*Radio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio) ***is*** the technology of signaling and communicating using radio waves. Radio waves are electromagnetic waves of frequency between 30 hertz (Hz) and 300 gigahertz (GHz)."

"[Radio broadcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_broadcasting) is transmission of audio (sometimes with related metadata) by radio waves intended to ***reach a wide audience***."

---

I realize I'm way to caught up on *radio*, but it's the only thing we have to go on for "sound producible", as it's all dependent on *how* the thing is capable of making sound. If it's *percussive* you have to hit it. If it requires electrical energy it's *electroacoustic*. If it relies solely on vibration and does not require electrical energy nor percussive force, it needs a resonance chamber or body, which is called *acoustic*.

Comment: What's the hypernym for a string, a reed, and the simple hole in the mouth of a flute? That should go after "resonance chamber or body" with another *or*.